# Is it safe to eat hard boiled eggs after washing with peroxide and cold water?

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I read that washing eggs with cold water will draw bacteria from the outer shell inward the egg.

Are hard boiled eggs made with eggs washed with peroxide and rinsed with cold water before cooking safe to eat? I am concerned about the cold water I used to clean the porous shell.

Comment: Where are you located? In the US, commercially produced eggs are required to be washed before being sold.

Comment: And you may remember that boiling destroys bacteria as well.

Comment: It's hard to tell whether this is a valid concern about farm eggs & non-pottable water, or paranoia over supermarket eggs.

Comment: Another question: by "peroxide", do you mean hydrogen peroxide or a different [peroxide-based bleach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxide-based_bleach)?

Comment: Additional note: the FDA does advise against washing other foods when it is deemed to be unsafe; see the "1. Clean:" section of [this article](https://www.fda.gov/consumers/consumer-updates/food-safety-tips-healthy-holidays). However, if you are not cooking in the US, you may give more weight to the advice of your local food safety authority.

Comment: While not an exact match for this question, [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/22981/72906) includes a link to FDA guidelines for cooking eggs and explains some of the reasoning behind them. The link in the answer is broken; [this new article from the FDA](https://www.fda.gov/food/buy-store-serve-safe-food/what-you-need-know-about-egg-safety) appears to contain the same advice.

Comment: Until the 70s we even boiled (5 minutes I guess) syringes for injections  Given that a sold egg should be ok and to make a hard egg takes about 10 minutes, I would feel mindless.

Comment: @Alchimista „mindless“? May be because I‘m not a native speaker, but I don’t really get it?

Comment: @Stephie - I *am* an English native & I'm not sure what point it's trying to make either;) Additionally, I've vtc'd this as 'too broad' because we need too many additional details before it's answerable at all.

Comment: Sorry forgot the real meaning of mindless. I feel the entire story about a hard egg is mindless. But I know others have different views and show an epidemiological approach corroborated by big number effect. The only question that would make sense here, and suitable for Biology SE, is "is it true that washing eggs with (cold) water facilitates bacteria to diffuse inwards? ".